# getMediaStream interference from WebConferencing tools (Webex, GotoMeeting, etc.)

Tags: electron, chromium, web-mediarecorder

Using electron/chromium getMediaStream API results in a black capture when programs like Webex and GotoMeeting have screen/application capture running. Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

No there is way to solve this (but you catch the exception and display proper message).
This because at any given point of time only application can use this feature (just like webcam access)